# DataTables column not keep fixed

Tags: angular, datatables

Column data does not keep fixed when table is scroll. Only the column header keep fixed.

[First column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7beCL.png)

[First column after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzm5u.jpg)

**Template**

Current table code

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped">
<thead>

</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let tda of turmaDisciplinaAlunos;  let j = index;">
        <th>{{tda.numSequencia}}</th>
        <td>{{tda.aluno.codigo}}</td>
        <td>{{tda.aluno.nome}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let notaParcial of notasParciais; let i = index;">
            <input class="w-25" [(ngModel)]="turmaDiscAlunoNotas[j][i].nota" (change)="handleChange(turmaDiscAlunoNotas[j][i])">
        </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Component**

DataTable configurations

```
createTable() {
    let columns = [{title:'NºSeq'},{title:'Codigo'},{title:'Nome'}]
    this.avaliacoes.forEach( obj => {
        columns.push({title:obj.nome});
    })
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        scrollY: "500px",
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: false,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        fixedColumns: true,
        ordering:false,
        columns: columns,
        "columnDefs": [
            { "width": "50px", "targets": [0,1] },
            { "width": "200px", "targets": 2 },
            { "width": "100px", "targets": "_all" }
          ]
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: Data doens't keep aligned with first header column. Look that linked image.

Comment: @renantins can u draw a live fiddle on http://live.datatables.net/ ?

Comment: @vibs2006 I added more one image

Comment: @renantins I'm not able to reproduce the html. If you are using angular then you can use angular fiddle at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjjggn?file=main.ts